# Permission denied error when building SONY CameraRemote SDK sample application in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake, permission-denied, sony

I'm building the sample application of SONY CameraRemote SDK named RemoteCli in XCode, and it calls CMake to build it. However I've met the permission denied error in building with the message shown below:

```
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/local/./RemoteCli
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:56 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file
  "/Users/username/work/build/Release/RemoteCli" to
  "/usr/local/./RemoteCli": Permission denied.
```

I've tried the `sudo chmod -R 777` command to change the authority of the `/usr/local/` folder but it does not work, and some of the folders also refused to change the authority. Could anyone tell me how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

System: macOS 10.15.6 with XCode 11.6
CMake: 3.19.1

Answer (score 1):

You are trying not only to build it, but also to *install* it on your system!

There should be another .cmake file that does only build that sample app.

The path with the /./ looks dubious to me. And be thankful that your chmod command did not work. Better check that you did not break anything important in /usr/local...

Comment: I installed CMake from its official site and then added it to the PATH as Tools -> How to install for command line use said by running `PATH="/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin":"$PATH"` in the Terminal

Comment: I've found the problem and solved it! Just because I accidentally set the scheme to "target: install > My Mac" and this is why XCode and CMake try to install the application! Change the scheme back to RemoteCli > My Mac then everything works fine! Thank you for your answer!